# VBA DoCmd.TransferText - exporting table to .csv without quotation marks (text qualifier)

Tags: ms-access, vba

How to export the table into csv format using access vba code?

I can able to export into csv format, but i need the output without quotation marks in the csv file.

Actual Results:

```
"scenario 1",17.00,100.00,"75",20.00,"Albert","Detweiler",13-04-1963 0:00:00,"123 Main","Mesa","AZ",85282.00
"scenario 2",16.00,75.00,"A3",5.24,"Benjamin","Detweiler",06-07-1973 0:00:00,"123 Main","Mesa","AZ",85282.00
```

Expected results:

```
scenario 1,17.00,100.00,75,20.00,Albert,Detweiler,13-04-1963 0:00:00,123 Main,Mesa,AZ,85282.00
scenario 2,16.00,75.00,A3,5.24,Benjamin,Detweiler,06-07-1973 0:00:00,123 Main,Mesa,AZ,85282.00
```

Someone please help for this question. Thanks in advance!

Sample code:

```
Option Compare Database

Sub exportQuery()
    Dim exportSQL As String
    Dim db As DAO.Database, qd As DAO.QueryDef
    Dim fd As FileDialog
    Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs)

    Set db = CurrentDb

    'Check to see if querydef exists
    For i = 0 To (db.QueryDefs.Count - 1)
        If db.QueryDefs(i).Name = "Sheet1" Then
            db.QueryDefs.Delete ("Sheet1")
            Exit For
    End If
    Next i

    Set qd = db.CreateQueryDef("Sheet8", exportSQL)

    'Set intial filename
    fd.InitialFileName = "export_" & Format(Date, "mmddyyy") & ".csv"

    If fd.Show = True Then
        If Format(fd.SelectedItems(1)) <> vbNullString Then
            DoCmd.TransferText acExportDelim, "Standard Output ", "Sheet1", fd.SelectedItems(1), False
        End If
    End If

    'Cleanup
    db.QueryDefs.Delete "Sheet1"
    db.Close
    Set db = Nothing
    Set qd = Nothing
    Set fd = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Edit your export specification or create a new one from scratch.  Either way, select `{none}` from the Text Qualifier dropdown.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Export CSV file from Access without double quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23255449/export-csv-file-from-access-without-double-quotes)